# Linker generates undefined references derived templated class instance

Tags: templates, linker, abstract-class

I have the following abstract class -

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

template <typename T>
class FOO{

 public:
  virtual void bar();

 protected:
  T foobar;


};


#endif
```

I then derive from this class -

```
#ifndef BAH_H
#define BAH_H

#include "foo.h"

template <typename T>
class BAH : public FOO<T>{

 public:
  BAH();
  void bar(T const &);


};


#endif


////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Class Methods
////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<class T>
void BAH<T>::bar(T const &)
{




}
```

I then create main

```
#include "bah.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  FOO<int> *i_bah = new BAH<int>();



}
```

and on compilation 
% gcc main.cpp -I./

I get this from the linker -
/tmp/ccQmTxZi.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to`operator new(unsigned long)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `BAH<int>::BAH()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to`operator delete(void*)'
/tmp/ccQmTxZi.o:(.eh_frame+0x13): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Caan anyone tell me what's going ???

Comment: You need to compile with `g++ ...`, not `gcc ...`.

Comment: Hi Paul, Good Catch... I updated and made a slight fix to bah.h

Comment: Now on compilation I get this -/tmp/ccHkpAXl.o:(.rodata._ZTV3BAHIiE[vtable for BAH<int>]+0x10): undefined reference to `FOO<int>::bar()'
/tmp/ccHkpAXl.o:(.rodata._ZTV3FOOIiE[vtable for FOO<int>]+0x10): undefined reference to `FOO<int>::bar()'

Comment: Can you update your question so that it has the latest version of your code, the latest g++ command line you are using, and the error messages ?

Comment: One thing I think you need to change: in `class FOO`, `virtual void bar();` should probably be: `virtual void bar() = 0;` (i.e. it needs to be pure virtual).

Comment: I will try your suggestion, I have update the pose as you requested -

Comment: The post is called "Linker generates undefined references derived templated class instance - code update with fix"

Comment: Hi Paul, Yous comment makes sense, tried making pure virtual but got this -main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:6: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'BAH<int>'
bah.h:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'BAH<int>':
foo.h:8: note:  void FOO<T>::bar() [with T = int]